# How come the Children of the Forest don't use dragonglass weapons?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In episode 5 of season 6, there is a battle scene between a Child of the Forest and a White Walker: [click here to watch the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Poy6h2zJCJ0#t=0m42s).

The Child of the Forest is using ordinary weapon, not made of dragonglass. I find it weird,  because since they are those who created the White Walkers, the Children of the Forest should know the best that dragonglass weapons can destroy them.

Is there any explanation for this odd behavior? Using dragonglass weapons might not have saved them, but surely help to delay the attack and buy Bran precious time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's low quality but you can actually see it in the clip before the White Walker comes in that, that particular Child of the Forest uses a spear to one shot a few wights. This only works because these are dragonglass spears, the same that Meera throws at that White Walker killing it afterwards because she hits it in an unarmoured spot.

[image: The dragonglass spear kills the wight]

The reason it doesn't kill the White Walker is simply because the dragonglass tip never penetrates the armour.

[image: The Child of the Forest attacks the White Walker, spear tip into the belly armour]

Comment: So simple and obvious. Feeling bit (well, a lot! ;)) stupid now but thanks for pointing it out! :)

Comment: On second thought and more analyze, think the reason why I didn't realize this is that in **all** other scenes showing dragonglass and white walkers, the walkers just going poof instantly, it's barely even showing them being hit. So this make one believe that it's super easy to do it, and totally forger White Walker can wear armor just like any other warrior. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 I think you need to penetrate the skin, but any penetration will do it. Most of the time we see it done is with a forceful strike with a more powerful weapon (Valyrian Steel) or into an unarmoured spot.

Comment: Interesting. Very, actually. Any existing question about it here already? (How White Walkers can be killed.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 It's been a while so I can't remember exact details but I did [answer this on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/168028/58193) a while back. Looks like it was [asked here as well](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100454/45378).